# Bibliography entries as hyperlink to PDF

Tags: bibliographies

I'd like to display my bibliography as usual. However, the entire entry for each article should point to a link that I additionally provide in the bibtex entry. For example:

```
@inproceedings{ying2018graph,
  title={Graph convolutional neural networks for web-scale recommender systems},
  author={Ying, Rex and He, Ruining and Chen, Kaifeng and Eksombatchai, Pong and Hamilton, William L and Leskovec, Jure},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 24th ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery \& Data Mining},
  pages={974--983},
  year={2018},
  organization={ACM},
  pdflink={!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! LINK TO PDF HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
}
```

Do you know of any library that can already do this?

Or do you know about some way to modify the bibliography entry creation such that every part of the entry (not just the title as proposed [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22551)) points to a pdf in the internet?

Comment: with biblatex/biber you could put the link in the url field or the file field, it should work out-of-the box.

Comment: Alright. Thanks! I'll give it a try.